# Odd behaviour with vb.NET / asmx / Mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, asmx

I am developing a windows based VB.NET application that works with mysql as the back end and in the web server. I am connecting to the database using a web service (asmx) and all operations are working perfectly. Sometimes for some SELECT queries it produces no result (no errors either) and for the same query it will generate results after an hour or in the next day. Because of this behaviour, I can't find any tipe of an error and continue the project.

Thanks in advance if you can give me an idea of what's happening

the code is below

```
<SoapHeader("Authentication")> _
<WebMethod(Description:="Get the result from sql query - Returns a Dataset")> _
Public Function ExecuteQuery(ByVal strQuery As String) As DataSet

    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet 'create a DataSet to hold the results
    If decryptString(Authentication.Username) = "bla bla" AndAlso decryptString(Authentication.Password) = "bla blah" Then

        Try

            'create a MySqlCommand to represent the query
            If sqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                sqlConn = New MySqlConnection(conStr)
                sqlConn.Open()
            End If

            Dim sqlcmd As MySqlCommand = sqlConn.CreateCommand()
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            sqlcmd.CommandText = strQuery

            'create a MySqlDataAdapter object
            Dim sqlDa As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
            sqlDa.SelectCommand = sqlcmd

            Try
                'fill the DataSet using the DataAdapter
                sqlDa.Fill(ds, "Results")
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw New ApplicationException("Error-luckie's server 1 " & ex.Message)
            End Try

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New ApplicationException("Error-luckie's server 2 " & ex.Message)
        Finally
            sqlConn.Close()
            sqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try

    End If
    Return ds

End Function
```

Comment: I found it is something like MySql is sleeping for a while before answering SELECT queries and once answered it will always be there until new data are there and it sleeps again. Funny, but this is what i felt. May be it will help you helping me.

Comment: Some code? Are you closing your connection?

Comment: paste your code please

Comment: Found after playing with .Net connector (it was 5.0.9). With the latest update, It started working. Thanks for all the help.